# Installing Cassandra Java Driver on Lucee

Tags: java, coldfusion, cassandra, railo, lucee

I'm not very seasoned on Java, but I'm trying to setup Cassandra as Datasource in Lucee using "Other OBDC,"  And I'm hitting some road blocks.   I believe I need to install this - https://github.com/datastax/java-driver on my server, but I'm assuming this has to be compiled as a Jar, which I have no idea how to do.  And then saved into the /opt/lucee/lib folder, which I do know how to do.

Also, I already tried the method explained in this post - [Using Apache Cassandra In Coldfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584607/using-apache-cassandra-in-coldfusion), but I think the jars are older, and don't seem to work with what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the [binary tarball](http://www.datastax.com/download-drivers) on their download page?

Comment: Yeah, I unpacked it in the opt/lucee/lib directory and then restarted Lucee. 

I get the following error now - 
can't find class [com.datastax.driver.auth] for jdbc driver, check if driver (jar file) is inside lib folder (cannot load class through its string name, because no definition for the class with the specified name [com.datastax.driver.auth] could be found)

I've tried a number of the classes from the API - http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/index.html?overview-summary.html 

and keep getting the same response

Comment: Exactly which jars did you place in /opt/lucee/lib? The tarball contains several, some in sub folders. You need to place the main Cassandra Driver jars in that folder, plus any dependencies (I am not sure what those are)

Comment: cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.7.jar,
cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.7.jar,
cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.7.jar,
cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.jar,
/lib/

There was a lib folder in the jar, which I assume had the dependencies.  Which now sits as a directory within the lucee/lib directory

Comment: guava-14.0.1.jar, lz4-1.2.0.jar, netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar, netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar, netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar, snappy-java-1.0.5.jar, 
HdrHistogram-2.1.4.jar, metrics-core-3.0.2.jar, netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar, netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

Comment: I have not used Cassandra, so I don't know the answer. However, you should move the jar list, and full error message, into the question so they are more visible. That might attract more attention. (The redundant comments can be deleted)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the binary tarball from http://www.datastax.com/download-drivers and installed the jar files and dependencies (found in `/lib`) in the Lucee **web-context** (`WEB-INF\lucee\lib`) and restarted Lucee.

```
<cfset ClusterInit = CreateObject("java", "com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster">
<!--- lists the methods in the Cluster class --->
<cfdump var="#ClusterInit#" abort="true">
```

This did not work when I put the jar files in the server folder (`lucee\lib`) so maybe you want to try that.

Hope this helps.